# SSDT - CROSS APPLY OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server-data-tools, cross-apply

Trying to write a stored procedure in SSDT like below:

```
            CREATE PROCEDURE Response.TransformHotel
                @RequestIDs Request.RequestIDs READONLY
            AS
            BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO response.Hotel
                SELECT EventID, 
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.Id') AS HotelID,
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.HasSpecialOffer') AS HasSpecialOffer,
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.HasClosedUserGroupSpecialOffer') AS HasClosedUserGroupSpecialOffer,
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.ReviewSummary.AverageScore') AS AvarageScore,
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.PercentageScore') AS PercentageScore,
                    JSON_VALUE(x.[value], '$.NumberOfReviews') AS NumberOfReviews
                FROM Search.[Event] E
                INNER JOIN @RequestIDs R ON R.RequestID = E.EventID
                CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(E.MessageEvent, '$.Response.SearchResults') AS x
            END
```

But it is giving me error "SQL46010: Incorrect Syntax near E."

However, if I write this on SSMS and execute it I get no issues.

I tried with another stored procedure and it seems OPENJSON is not available in SSDT.

```
            CREATE PROCEDURE Request.TestOpenJSON
            AS
                SELECT * FROM
                OPENJSON( (SELECT E.MessageEvent FROM search.Event E WHERE E.EventID = 1))
```

Visual Studio Profesional 2015

Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

.NET Framework Version 4.6.010555

Project Settings:
Target Platform: SQL Server 2016

Has anyone got any ideas?  Rather not refactor the query to resolve a SSDT problem if possible.

I have used JSON VALUE and JSON QUERY throughout the project and not had any issues.

Ideas passed around is to add this as a post deploy script which also isn't great as it's a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: Which version of SSDT do you show loaded when you go to Help - About?

Comment: Version 14.0.60525.0
https://s32.postimg.org/43tr68251/vs_version.png

Comment: Definitely the latest release as of this moment. I'd open a Connect ticket and/or ping the SSDT team on Twitter about this.  And yes, you can always do a post-deploy script as a work-around. It's not ideal, but at least gets you past this particular problem.

Comment: Just got the same error in my project as well. Seems like they haven't added proper support for JSON to SSDT yet.

Comment: Please vote on the corresponding Connect issue so that we can get the fix faster - https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2820804/ssdt-fails-to-compile-post-deploy-script-with-erroneous-sql72007-error

Comment: Got in touch with microsoft.

"This is a known issue with the parser used by the database projects.  We unfortunately do not have this fixed in the June 30th SSDT release.  We should have a fix available for the July 30th release."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late to answer but I had the same problem with the openjson instruction when I found this post, so here my results. If you restore a database from Sql Server 2012 (for example, without support of openjson) into a Sql Server 2016, the compatibility level remains in Sql Server 2012. You have to upgrade the database (not the engine) to level 130 or better:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb510680.aspx